# how to export function from composition api vuejs 3

Tags: vue.js

```
// File2.vue
<script>
  import { ref, computed } from 'vue';
  let ex = ref(1);

  const sum = computed(() => {
    let value = 5 + 5;
    return value
  });

</script>

<template>
  <div class="page">
    <span>No {{ ex }}</span>
  </div>
</template>
```

this is code from File2.vue

Now i want to import this `component` and `sum` function
in `Main.vue` file

i tried wrapping that `sum` function inside `setup` and exported
and imported then new error warning showing
`Property "ex" was accessed during render but is not defined on instance`

Comment: It should be <script setup>...</script>

Comment: Place reusable exports to .js, not .vue

Answer (score 0):

vue files can't compile to different code it doesn't accept `export` something out of file
maybe you are looking for something like `defineExpose`

Counter.vue

```js
<template>
  <button @click="counter++">count: {{ counter }}</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const counter = ref(0)

defineExpose({ counter })
</script>
```

App.vue

```js
<template>
  <Counter ref="counterRef" />

  Count in Counter: {{ counterRef?.counter }}
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
const counterRef = ref<InstanceType<typeof Counter>>()
</script>
```